# Unable to Connect MongoLab with Cakephp?

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp

I am using cakephp with MongoDB first time, i had use [this Plugin](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb) to for it. it works fine for me on mongoDb installed in my local system, but now i want's to connect my application with live MongoLab environment. so for that i am using this detail in my `app/config/database.php`

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Mongodb.MongodbSource',
    'host' => 'mongodb://username:password@ds123456.mongolab.com:12345,ds123456.mongolab.com:12345/sampleDB?replicaSet=rs-ds012345&ssl=true',
    'login' => 'myusername',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'database' => 'mydatabse',
    'prefix' => '',
    'persistent' => 'true'
);
```

but it give me error like `Notice (1024): SSL can only be 'true' or 'false' [APP\Plugin\Mongodb\Model\Datasource\MongodbSource.php, line 230]`

i had try with many combination of host, i had also try with following option

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Mongodb.MongodbSource',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'myusername',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'database' => 'mydatabse',
    'prefix' => '',
    'persistent' => 'true',
    'replicaset' => array('host' => 'mongodb://username:password@ds123456.mongolab.com:12345,ds123456.mongolab.com:12345/sampleDB?replicaSet=rs-ds012345&ssl=true',
      'options' => array('replicaSet' => 'rs-ds123456')
    )
);
```

as describe [Here](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/wiki/How-to-connect-to-replicaset-servers) but it also wont work for me.

Can anyone help me please.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you are using the riight MongoDB driver. You have [MongoDB driver (legacy)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php#book.mongo) and [MongoDB driver](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php).